# Independence of two processes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Suppose $X_t$ is the solution of the SDE

$$dX=a(X)dt+b_1(X)dW_1+b_2(X)dW_2$$

$Y_t$ is the solution of the following SDE

$$dY=p(Y)dt+q_1(Y)dW_1+q_2(Y)dW_2$$

Here, $W_1$ and $W_2$ are independent Brownian motions.

I am trying to prove that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. I have proven that $dXdY=0$, will this help? If this is not enough, which is what I thought, are there any other conditions I need to check? or some other ways I can try?

I appreciate any suggestions in advance.

Comment: quant.stackexchange.com I think can help too

Comment: @ DEW: You have too impose severe constraints on your coefficients for this to be true. For example take $a(x)=p(x)=0, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $b_1(x)=q_1(x)=1, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $b_2(x)=q_2(x)=0, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ then $X=Y$. Best regards

Comment: @BCLC Thank you. I will have a try.

Comment: @TheBridge Thank you for your answer. But in my case the coefficients are not that special and changing them is not an option. I thought there might be some general conditions I need to check.

Comment: @DEW As TheBridge pointed out, the statement does not hold because - in general - the solutions are correlated. Actually, I doubt even that $dX dY=0$ holds true.

Comment: @saz Thank you. I agree that in general the solutions are correlated. I am wondering if there is any more "general" constraints on the coefficients than the ones TheBridge mentioned, such that $X$ and $Y$ may be independent. About $dXdY=0$, if I can prove $b_1q_1+b_2q_2=0$, then it is right, isn't it?

Comment: I see. (And yes, if $b_1q_1+b_2q_2 = 0$, then $dX dY=0$ -but you didn't mention this condition in your question.)

Comment: @saz Sorry I forgot to mention that. Thank you for your help :)